# bash script to read first argument as input and look for variable in another file line by line

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a file "input.txt" has variables A1, A2, A3, θ, θ1 and θ2 - sample of input.txt is as follows:

```
$ cat input1.txt 

A1=5.2 A2=4.9  A3=6.1 θ=space    θ1=2.5 θ2=1.2 

A1=3.1 A2=5.1  A3=3.7 θ=triangle θ1=8.1 θ2=3.9
```

I want to create a script to run over the file input.txt - this file will be passed as a second argument, the first argument would be the value of θ

I created a script as follows:

```
#! /bin/bash

file=input1.txt

if grep -q $1 "$file"; 
then
awk -F '[= ]+' '{ print $12 }' <$2

else

echo "Not available"
fi
}
```

But when I run this script as follows:

```
./script space input.txt
```

(first argument is the value of θ and second argument is the file name), the output is all the values in field 12:

```
$ ./script1 space input1.txt 
1.2
3.9
```

the output should be 1.2 only, I searched and found that I need to create a loop to read the file line by line but I can not get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

You can do all the work in `awk`:

```
#!/bin/sh
file=$2

awk -v theta="$1" -F '[= ]+' '
        $0 ~ theta { print $12; found++ }
        END        { if (!found) { print "Not available"; exit 1 } }' "$file"
```

You might want to add error handling to verify
that there are two command-line arguments,
and `$2` is the name of a readable file, because

- if `$2` is something other than a readable file,
  you will get an error message from `awk`
- if `$2` is blank or absent,
  `awk` will silently read from the standard input.

(Of course, either or both of these behaviors might be OK with you.)

Notes:

- You may get more targeted results by changing `$0 ~ theta` to `$8 == theta`.
- Variables in `awk` are initialized to blank. 
  This is treated as 0 in mathematical contexts, so `found++` sets `found` to 1 the first time it is executed. 
  I deliberately said `found++` instead of `found = 1` so,
  if multiple lines match the theta value,
  `found` will be set to the *number* of such lines. 
  This seems like it should be an error condition;
  if you are concerned about it, you can modify the `END` block
  to report an error if `found` is anything other than 1.
- Of course, if you need your script to do one thing if a value is found
  and something else if it isn't,
  you can delete the `print` statement from the `END` block
  and have the script just test `awk`'s exit status
  and issue its own error message.  You should also do this
  if you want to capture the output from the `awk` (i.e., the θ2 value). 
  Conversely, if all you need is a human-readable error message,
  and you don't need to be able to check exit status,
  you can delete the `exit` statement from the `END` block.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#! /bin/bash

file=input1.txt

if grep -q $1 "$file";
then
        grep $1 $2 | awk -F '[= ]+' '{ print $12 }'
else
        echo "Not available"
fi
```

Comment: I would like to thank every one who replied to my question, it was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your logic can be boiled down to:

```
grep -om1 "$1" < "$2" ||
echo 'Not available.'
```

...provided a GNU `grep`, anyway. Though, if it were me, I would drop the `echo`, or at least do...

```
! echo 'Not available.' >&2
```

...instead.

Comment: With that script, the command `./script1 space input1.txt` will output `space`, whereas the desired output is `1.2` (i.e., the `θ2` value from the `θ=space` line).